Woocommerce: добавить класс в товар, используя ACF
Пытаюсь добавить класс для товара, используя add_filter + значение ACF (True/false), но не работает:
add_filter('post_class', function($classes, $class, $product_id) {
  if(is_product_category() && get_field('product_new',$product_id))
  {
    $classes = array_merge(['product_new_class'], $classes);
  }
return $classes;}, 10,3);

